# Can "LL" be removed from a hard-coded integer constant, and be replaced by "static_cast<uint64_t>(...)"?

Tags: c++

I am modifying legacy code that utilizes a "long long" (`LL`) data type definition for a hard-coded constant, as follows:

```
0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFLL
```

I trust that the `LL` appended to the constant guarantees that this constant will be interpreted as a `long long`.

However, I do not want to depend on `long long` having any particular compiler-dependent interpretation in terms of the number of bits.

Therefore, I would like my variable declaration to do without the `LL` in the constant, and instead use:

```
uint64_t a = static_cast<uint64_t>(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF);
```

I would like to think that the constant `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` is not interpreted by the compiler as a 32-bit integer BEFORE the cast to `uint64_t`, which would result in `a` being a 64-bit integer that contained the value `0xFFFFFFFF`, rather than the desired value.

(My current 64-bit compilers of interest are VS 2010, and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS GCC.  However, I would hope that this code behaves in the desired way for any modern compiler.)

Will the above code work as desired for most or all modern compilers, so the the value of `a` is properly set to include all digits, as desired, from the constant `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`, WITHOUT including the `LL` at the end of the constant?

(Note: Including `I64` at the end of the constant gives a compiler error.  Perhaps there is another token that needs (or can) be included at the end of the constant to tell the compiler to interpret the constant as a 64-bit integer?)

(Also: Perhaps even the `static_cast<uint64_t>` is unnecessary, since the variable is explicitly being defined as uint64_t?)

Comment: We know that `long long` must be *at least* 64 bits. Would it be a problem it the type was even wider?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reduce what Andy says to the essentials: if the implementation has one or more standard integer types that is capable of representing `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`, then the literal `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` has *one* of those types.

It doesn't really matter to you which one, since no matter which it is, the result of the conversion to `uint64_t` is the same.

If the (pre-C++11) implementation doesn't have any integer type big enough, then (a) the program is ill-formed, so you should get a diagnostic; and (b) it *probably* won't have `uint64_t` anyway.

You are correct that the `static_cast` is unnecessary. It does the same conversion that assigning to `uint64_t` would do anyway. Sometimes a cast will suppress compiler warnings that you get for certain implicit integer conversions, but I think it's unlikely that any compiler would warn for an implicit conversion in this case. Often there won't be one, since `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` will commonly have type `uint64_t` already.

As an aside, it's probably better to write `static_cast<uint64_t>(-1)`, or just `uint64_t a = -1;`. It's guaranteed to be equal to `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`, but it's much easier for a reader to see the difference between `-1` and `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` than it is to see the difference between `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` and `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: I was hoping someone would mention the aside. There's no reason to try to come up with the exact maximum value and hope it'll work, when unsigned -1 is defined to be the maximum.

Answer (score 5):

Per Paragraph 2.1.14/2 of the C++11 Standard:

> The type of an integer literal is the first of the corresponding list in Table 6 in which its value can be
>   represented

Table 6 specifies that for hexadecimal literal constants, the type of the literal should be:

- `int`; or (if it doesn't fit)
- `unsigned int`; or (if it doesn't fit)
- `long int`; or (if it doesn't fit)
- `unsigned long int`; or (if it doesn't fit)
- `long long int`; or (if it doesn't fit)
- `unsigned long long int`.

If we make the reasonable assumption that `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` will not fit in any of the first 5 types from the above list, its type should be `unsigned long long int`. As long as you are working with a 64 bit compiler, it is reasonable to assume that values of this type will have a size of 64 bit, and the constant will be interpreted as a 64-bit `unsigned long long int`, as you hoped.

Comment: "Since `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` does not fit" - should be "probably will not fit" since, for example, there's no reason `unsigned int` can't be 64 bits.

Comment: Also, I think some copy and pasting screwed up the type names. Bullets 2 and 3 are messed up.

Comment: @sftrabbit: Indeed, I edited that as well. Thank you again :)

Comment: Do you know if this is likely to apply to compilers, such as Ubuntu 12.04 LTS GCC, which are not C++11 compliant, and which are not even fully C++0x compliant?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: Honestly, I'm not sure. Did `uint64_t` exist at all before C++11? I don't believe so. I don't even know whether those compilers support it, but if they do, I would expect them tp comply with the related parts of the C++11 Standard. I can't tell for sure though

Comment: `uint64_t` existed in C99 before C++11. Since gcc has supported C99 for years (with some defects that aren't relevant to this), its version of `uint64_t` does conform.